# Combining attached photos in kmail

Tags: archive, kmail

Someone has sent me an email with about 30 attached jpeg files.  It's extremely tedious to view them by clicking on them one by one.  Is there a way to view them in a single viewer, sequentially?

It is obviously better for people to collect photos in archives, but I've generally been unable to persuade them of that.

Comment: Can you highlight all of them and then right-click mouse and select open or view?

Answer (score 0):

I would download all attachments together and view them with an image viewer like [Gwenview](https://userbase.kde.org/Gwenview). Right click on the email in the list and select download attachments. This feature is not available in an opened email, you must right click the email in the list of emails.